# Parsing JSON file using getJSON

Tags: jquery, html, json

New to the site. I am having major difficulties parsing json data into a collapsible list for a JQuery Mobile site. I can get the data to parse into a single div but not into separate div's so the div's will collapse. JSON file follows:

```
      JSON
      {"cycloCrossBikes":[
      {
        "Name":"Trek Boone 9 Disc",
        "ImgPath":"<img src=\"http://www.weraceshimano.com/ImageGen.ashx?width=465&constrain=True&image=/media/161868/Bike_picture_3800_pix_breed.jpg\">",
        "Description":"Boone is our fastest, smoothest, lightest Cross bike ever, with competition-crushing race geometry, and Trek's exclusive course-smoothing IsoSpeed technology. Mud, sweat, tears, triumph. You'll charge through it all with bigger speed, stronger lines, and more confidence than ever before. Boone is the ultimate Cyclocross superbike.",
        "Link":"http://www.trekbikes.com/ie/en/bikes/road/cyclocross/boone/"
      },
      {
        "Name":"Colnago Prestige",
        "ImgPath":"<img src=\"http://ep.yimg.com/ay/glorycycles/colnago-world-cup-disc-cross-bike-2014-1.gif\">",
        "Description":"Developed with input from cyclo-cross legend Sven Nys, the Cross Prestige is the ultimate carbon fibre cross frame. A monocoque front triangle makes it tough and light, while lugged seat stays and chain stays maximise tyre clearance. The lightness will also be appreciated when shouldering the Cross Prestige, as will the unique support between the top tube and seat tube developed at Sven Nys’s request to increase carrying comfort when on the shoulder.",
        "Link":"http://colnago.com/prestige-2/?lang=en"
      },
      {
        "Name":"Ridley X-Night 10",
        "ImgPath":"<img src=\"http://content.ridley-bikes.com/bikes/x-night-10-disc-lv-bel_1380019666993029.jpg\">",
        "Description":"The Ridley X-Night 1201D is Ridley's top end cross bike. Featuring the most advanced cross frame in the world, Mudless tube technology, and fully integrated Kevlar cable guides(for smooth shifting and cable life), it's in a class of it's own. ",
        "Link":"http://www.ridley-bikes.com/be/en/bikes/4/144/44/cyclocross/x-night-10-disc-lv-bel"
      }
      ]}
```

HTML file follows:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <style>
       </style>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-   1.4.2.css" />
       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
       <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        $.getJSON('json_list.json', function(data) {
           var output=" <div> ";
           for (var i in data.cycloCrossBikes) {
           output+="<h3>"+data.cycloCrossBikes[i].Name+"</h3>";
           output+= data.cycloCrossBikes[i].ImgPath;
           output+="<p>"+data.cycloCrossBikes[i].Description+"<p/>";
           output+="<a href="+data.cycloCrossBikes[i].Link+">Learn More</a>";
        }
           output+="</div>";
           document.getElementById("#cycloCrossBikes_List").innerHTML=output;
        });
       </script>
     <title>
     </title>
     </head>
     <body>
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
          <div data-role="collapsibleset" >
            <div data-role="collapsible" id="cycloCrossBikes_List">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: The question is not clear

Comment: Read the error console. If there are no errors, report the failing/unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing

```
document.getElementById("#cycloCrossBikes_List").innerHTML=output;
```

to

```
document.getElementById("cycloCrossBikes_List").innerHTML=output;
```

or even

```
$("#cycloCrossBikes_List").html(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're only opening and closing a single div tag. Try moving `var output=" <div> ";` and `output+="</div>";` inside the loop.